# Slick 2: Getting value of column in simple.Table class

Tags: playframework-2.0, slick

I have an SQL table called PRODUCT with 2 columns  (CODE VARCHAR and PATH VARCHAR). The last 4 characters in CODE are used to recognize the color of the product. I am using slick 2.0 like this:

```
import scala.slick.driver.H2Driver.simple._

case class Product(code: String, path: String, color: String)

class Products(tag: Tag) extends Table[Product](tag, "PRODUCTS") {
  def code = column[String]("CODE", O.PrimaryKey)
  def path = column[String]("PATH")
  def * = (code, path, "LAST 4 CHARS OF CODE") <> (Product.tupled, Product.unapply)
}
```

My problem is, that I would like to have the color in case class as a separated attribute. Is there a way, to get the String value (and the last 4 chars) from column CODE in class Products? Thx for the answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest answer would be to create a [computed column in H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#computed_columns) and define a color column in Slick:

```
class ProductTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Product](tag, "PRODUCTS") {
  def code = column[String]("CODE", O.PrimaryKey)
  def path = column[String]("PATH")
  def color = column[String]("COLOR", O.DBType("VARCHAR AS SUBSTR(PATH, LENGTH(PATH) - 3)"))
  def * = (code, path, color) <> (Product.tupled, Product.unapply)
}
```

Comment: Why can't we get the value from column? For example as code.value or something like that?

Comment: Lapi, see my alternative answer.

Answer (score 0):

Slick doesn't ship with a function for sub string operations. You could define it as `val substr = SimpleFunction.binary...` (see http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.0/userdefined.html). Then you can define `def color = substr(code, code.length-4)`. You may not want to include it in your `*` projection as the corresponding table ddl would probably fail (in case you need it). Instead you could use a separate projection (called something other than `*`).